# Configuration Manager Configuration Baseline evaluation schedule in the deployment vs client settings

Tags: sccm, configurationmanager, intune, system-center

How does the Configuration Manager Configuration Baseline evaluation schedule in the deployment settings work in conjunction with the evaluation schedule in the client settings? Does the evaluation schedule in the deployment take precedence over the evaluation schedule from the client settings?
For testing, I have set the "Specify the compliance evaluation schedule for this configuration baseline" in the deployment to 1 minute, but it is not running every minute. If I run the CB manually, it runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Baseline minimum schedule is 15 minutes, you can't set anything lower than that.
Here is the baseline schedule takes precedence. You can set lower than 15 but it won't take effect
I hope I could help